# How to find N,C,Z,V flags after the execution of this ARM assembly code program?

Tags: assembly, arm, flags

Giving the following ARM assembly code, find the the output of the ALU flags [Negative, Carry out, Zero, oVerflow]

```
MOV R0 #00000100
MOV R1 #00000100
MOV R2 #0000010A
CMP R0, R1
SUBGES R0, R0, R2
ADDLTS R0, R1, R2
```

The correct answer should be N=1 ; C=V=Z=0 but I'm not sure about it. Also, I'm not even sure if `#00000100` is binary, decimal or hexadecimal.
Anyways, considering all of them hexadecimal, I'm proceeding in this way:

```
CMP R0 R1
```

Gives as ALU flags Z=1 and C=V=N=0.

```
SUBGES R0, R0, R2
```

performs a subtracion if "Greater or equal" (checks if N==V). Since N=V,
 *R0-R2 = 256 - 266 = -10*
Recall that "S" uodates flags, N=1, C=Z=V=0.

```
ADDLTS R0, R1, R2
```

performs an addition if "Less Than" (checks if N!=V). Since N!=V, 
*R1 + R2 = 256 + 266 = 522*
It means that **N=C=Z=V=0**.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: I agree with your result, and qemu does too. PS: the `CMP R0 R1` will give `C=1` but that has no influence on the result.

Comment: well the 10A is hex, yes?  so assume the other two are as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update for those who may be interested in this question:**
My professor made a mistake, that's all. The correct answer is that I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

The *correct* answer makes sense if the instructions are `subge` and `addlt`.  It is rare (but is possible) to have a conditional and set.  Usually this would be an error.  See for instance the example below from the ARM ARM 2nd edition by David Seal,

```
/* C code for Euclid’s Greatest Common Divisor (GCD)*/
/* Returns the GCD of its two parameters */
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
  while (a != b)
    if (a > b )
      a = a - b ;
    else
      b = b - a ;
  return a ;
}

; ARM assembler code for Euclid’s Greatest Common Divisor
; On entry: R0 holds ‘a’, R1 holds ‘b’
; On exit : R0 hold GCD of A and B
gcd:
 CMP    R0, R1        ; compare ‘a’ and ‘b’
 SUBGT  R0, R0, R1    ; if (a>b) a=a-b (if a==b do nothing)
 SUBLT  R1, R1, R0    ; if (b>a) b=b-a (if a==b do nothing)
 BNE    gcd           ; if (a!=b) then keep going
 MOV    PC, LR        ; return to caller
```

It is very dense code that would both execute conditionally and set flags.  An obvious counter is (also from ARM ARM 2nd edition),

```
if (a==0 || b==1)
  c = d + e ;

CMP    R0, #0      ; compare a with 0
CMPNE  R1, #1      ; if a is not 0, compare b to 1
ADDEQ  R2, R3, R4  ; if either was true c = d + e
```

If everything in your question is correct, then the *correct answer* is wrong.

```
CMP R0, R1
SUBGES R0, R0, R2
ADDLTS R0, R1, R2  ; why bother setting conditions here?
```

This maps to,

```
   if(a <= b) {
     if(a <= c)
       a = b + c;
     else
       /* a = a */ ;
   } else {
       a = a - c;
   }
```

which leaves the case `a <= b &&  a > c` as the original `a`.  It is possible, but it seems a little contrived.  The form,

```
CMP R0, R1
SUBGE R0, R0, R2
ADDLT R0, R1, R2
```

Is much more practical.  If somehow this is Thumb2 code with a preceding `IT`, and you missed disassembling it, then disassembly will present `subge` as `subs` if things are correct.  It could be some sort of disassembler bug; but it seems like a paper and pencil homework question.  I guess a point here is that in Thumb2 and unified assembler, these forms (`subges`/`addlts`) aren't even allowed.